# I am getting error ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_37 to have shape (8, 8, 32) but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)

Tags: valueerror

I have a a data of shape as such:
x_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)
x_test shape: (3000, 32, 32, 3)
I further created test and validation sets of shapes as such :
validation data: (7000, 32, 32, 3) 
test data: (3000, 32, 32, 3)

Now I am using above sets to create a simple autoencoder model

```
    input_img = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
# encoder model
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(input_img) #  32 filters, filter shape = 3X3;Output shape of this layer with padding same; 
#(p = (f-1)/2) =1; ((n+2p-f)/s)+1 = (32+2-3)+1 = 32X32Xnumof filters = 32X32X32
x = BatchNormalization()(x) # batch normalization does not change shape - 32X32X32
x = Activation('relu')(x) # Activation does not change shape - 32X32X32
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x) # If stride is not specified , it defaults to pool size which is 2; That is 16X16X32
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(x) # stride = 1;((n+2p-f)/s +1) = (16+2-3)+1 = 16X16X32(32 is number of filters)
x = BatchNormalization()(x) # Doesnt change shape
x = Activation('relu')(x) # Dosent change shape
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
encoder.summary()

encoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
history = encoder.fit(x_train, x_train_noisy,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_val, x_val_noisy),
                    callbacks=[es_cb, cp_cb],
                    shuffle=True)
```

My Model looks like this

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_24 (InputLayer)        (None, 32, 32, 3)         0

---

conv2d_48 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 32)        896

---

batch_normalization_48 (Batc (None, 32, 32, 32)        128

---

activation_49 (Activation)   (None, 32, 32, 32)        0

---

max_pooling2d_36 (MaxPooling (None, 16, 16, 32)        0

---

conv2d_49 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 32)        9248

---

batch_normalization_49 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 32)        128

---

activation_50 (Activation)   (None, 16, 16, 32)        0

---

## max_pooling2d_37 (MaxPooling (None, 8, 8, 32)          0

Total params: 10,400
Trainable params: 10,272
Non-trainable params: 128

I keep getting error
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_37 to have shape (8, 8, 32) but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)
Where am I going wrong. It is as if the model did not compile at all. Some one please help